# Como utilizar el Widget del admin para agregar items

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

soy principiante en esto, la consulta es como puedo agregar en mi formulario  la imagen de "Edit" y "Add" en un campo choice y se me abra en un pop-up el formulario de ese modelo para agregarlo. Como lo hace el admin de Django pero quisiera hacerlo desde mi formulario. Gracias. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que logre hacer pero no logro actualizar el queryset luego de agregar el codigo:

Form.py:

```
class RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd(widgets.Select):

def __init__(self, related_model, related_url=None, *args, **kw):

    super(RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    if not related_url:
        rel_to = related_model
        info = (rel_to._meta.app_label, rel_to._meta.object_name.lower())
        related_url = 'admin:%s_%s_add' % info


    self.related_url = related_url

def render(self, name, value, *args, **kwargs):
    self.related_url = reverse(self.related_url)
    output = [super(RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd, self).render(name, value, *args, **kwargs)]
    output.append(u'<a href="%s" class="add-another" id="add_id_%s" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);"> ' % \
        (self.related_url, name))
    output.append(u'<img src="%sadmin/img/icon_addlink.gif" width="10" height="10" alt="%s"/></a>' % (settings.STATIC_URL, ('Add Another')))                                                                                                                               
    return mark_safe(u''.join(output))

class movimientoPacienteForm(forms.ModelForm):

   codigo = forms.ModelChoiceField(
   required = False,
   queryset = Codigo.objects.all(),
   widget = RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd(Codigo, 
        related_url="admin:principal_codigo_add")
                            )
class Meta:
    model = Cuenta
    exclude = 'paciente', 'operador', 'comentario', 'contabilizado', 'autoriza',
```

Movimiento.html

```
<form  id='formulario' method="POST" action=''>{% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ formulario|crispy }}
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn-sm btn-warning"></i></p></p>
                </div>
            </form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function showAddAnotherPopup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'{{title}}','height=200,width=600');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;}
</script>
```

Comment: Hay muchas formas y estoy seguro que todas ellas involucran, en mayor o menor medida, el uso de JavaScript. Aunque no recuerdo ningún ejemplo concreto en este momento, he visto soluciones con JS vainilla, jQuery y Angular.js. Busca una solución en Google e intenta aplicarla. Si te enfrentas con un problema rela y concreto, pregunta lo necesario y recuerda agregar un __[mcve]__.

Comment: Logré realizarlo con **class RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd(widgets.Select)** y JS como me indicaste. Pero aun no logro recargar el queryset después de que el nuevo codigo sea agregado.

Comment: @user2985566 que ¿queryset quieres refrescar? el que te sale del lado del front cuando agregaste un nuevo item o el del el backend cuando va a guardar la relación?

Comment: seria el del formulario principal, hago clic en agregar y se abre el popup agrego el item y al volver al formulario hasta que no actualizo la pagina no aparece el item que agregué. En le admin de Django no sucede eso! el item se agrega sin necesidad de actualizar la pagina.